# Method call - onActivityResult vs DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, dialog, chronometer

I just published a game on the Play Store and am planning to make it look better and more intuitive, si I'm trying to replace the Android dialogs by mines.

When the user finish a level, I need my custom dialog to show and if the user clicks some buttons, the dialog (which is an activity with a custom theme that make it looks like a dialog) have to return an integer with `setResult(customResult, intent)` and then finish.

The problem is that when I receive the resultCode in the `onActivityResult()` of the activity that did `startActivityForResult(intentCustomDialog, 0)`, I call a custom method that restart the level or launch the next one depending on the result (used to know what button the user clicked). This methods should also restarts the Chronometer, but it does nothing !!!!!!!
On the other side when I use the android dialog and I put the `restart()` call in the onClickListener the chronometer is successfully restarted !?

So what am I missing ? Why the `restart()` call successfully restart the chronometer with an `onClickListener` of the android dialogs but not when I call it from the `onActivityResult()` method ?

Would be very helpful so I could make my own dialogs implementation and use the `onActivityResult()` or even call a custom `onDialogResult()` method to separate `startActivityForResult()` launches of custom dialogs activities and normal activities.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

In my game class :

```
...
public static final int RESULT_RESTART = 8;
public static final int RESULT_NEXT = 9;
public static final int RESULT_MENU = 10;
...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (resultCode) {
        case RESULT_MENU:
            back(null);
            break;
        case RESULT_NEXT:
            nextGrid();
            break;
        case RESULT_RESTART:
            restartGrid();
            break;
    }
}
```

restartGrid() method :

```
public void restartGrid() {
    ...
    startChrono();
    ...
}

public void startChrono() {
    chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    chrono.start();
}
```

Works perfectly from a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`.

Comment: Are you sure `onActivityResult()` is called?

Comment: Yeah i'm sure because the views that was colored by the player are successfully reseted to their orginal colors. That's what make it so strange, the mechanism works perfeclty, only the chronometer is not reseted with no reason.

Comment: can you post chronometer code and `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Done. I edited my orignal post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could get it to work :

```
public void startChrono() {
    chrono.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chrono.start();
        }
    });
}
```

But I still don't understand why I have to do that for the chronometer as the views that have been colored are correctly reseted whithout using the post method...
Anyway it works :)